# Authenticate AWS copilot app with private Docker Hub repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, dockerhub

I am trying to deploy an app to AWS ECS using Copilot (https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/). I want to specify an image, not a Dockerfile, so that I don't have to build and push locally. However, my image on Docker Hub is private.

I've created an AWS secret with my credentials. I've edited my copilot manifest to try to use that secret:

```
image:
  location: my_repo/my_image
  repositoryCredentials:
    credentialsParameter: my_credentials_secret_ARN
```

However, I still get not found/not authorized when I deploy. If this is the right approach, what have I got wrong? If not, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I've been told by someone at AWS that copilot doesn't yet support building from an image hosted on a private repo. Hopefully the functionality will be coming soon.

Answer (score 2):

Follow progress on this request here:
https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/2101
https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/2061